# Calling external function from jquery (document).ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call a function in an external file from within a HTML page using the document.ready jquery functionality.  Below is the example of code from my HTML, but it does not execute the function with the code I've written.

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_js/script.js">
     //<![CDATA[
     $(document).ready(function(){
     // What do I run here to grab external file function?
         extFunction();
     });
     //]]/>
```

Example of function from external file:

```
function extFunction(){
    alert("ALERTED!");
};
```

Comment: what is the name of your external js file?

Comment: check your console and see if there errors

Comment: Try removing the src attribute on the script tag that contains the script. Alos, why do you have a CDATA tag in there

Comment: check in developer tool whether external JS is downloading or not..

Comment: Your JavaScript appears to be in a script tag that has a source. If you put your alert directly in the document ready function does it even run?

Comment: You were exactly right!  My fogged eyes didn't even notice I forgot to end the script for the source and start a new one!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

> > `<script type="text/javascript" src="_js/script.js">`

You cannot have a `src` attribute on a `<script>` tag and also have JavaScript code inside the tag. Once the `src` attribute is seen by the browser, it does not execute anything within the tag. Please make two separate tags...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_js/script.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
     $(document).ready(function(){
     // What do I run here to grab external file function?
         extFunction();
     });
     //]]/>
</script>
```

Comment: The first script tag needs a </script>.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot have body(content) and src for a script element

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     //<![CDATA[
     $(document).ready(function(){
     // What do I run here to grab external file function?
         extFunction();
     });
     //]]/>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to call function from a php file or js file ??
if you want to call a function of another .js file just include that file in your .js file and if you want to call a php function then use ajax.